# SQL Partition By Query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Looking for help with a TSQL query.
Lets say you are building Kitchen Cabinets. There are numerous parts to build 1 cabinet and a kitchen in turn will have numerous cabinets. Lets also say that we have 3 different types of cabinets (floor, upper and tall).
We have rack(s) where we want to put all the parts required to build the kitchen. However, we want to keep everything organized. So, Cabinet 1, we want to keep all its parts together.
Our Rack has numerous slots (so many per type of cabinet..upper, floor, tall). The slots can only hold so many pieces before it needs to spill over to the next slot.

So our database has a list of all the parts required per cabinet that is needed. The goal is to associate each part with a rack and slot #. We also know that there are cases where 1 cabinet will need numerous slots and a kitchen may require numerous racks.

How can you write a query to do this. Sample data below:
[image]

So The goal (referencing the row number - slot number).
1-1, 2-2, 3-3, 4-3, 5-3, 6-3, 7-3, 8-3, 9-4, 10-4......
Cabinet ID 32 needs 3 slots. So we want to show that you are going to start in slot 3, fill it, move to slot 4, fill it and then move on to slot 5.

I have separate tables that tell me how many slots per slot type are in a rack.
I am using the following so far:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.[CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet ID] , 
                dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].Width , 
                dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].Length , 
                dbo.[CAD-CV-MateriaIs].Name , 
                dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].AutoID , 
                dbo.[CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] ,
                CASE WHEN [CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] IN(3) THEN 'Tall' 
                        WHEN [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] IN(1 , 12 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7) THEN 'Lower' 
                        WHEN [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] IN(2 , 9 , 8 , 10 , 11 , 13 , 14) THEN 'Upper' 
                        ELSE 'No Cart' END AS SlotType,
                CASE WHEN [CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] IN(3)
                    THEN ceiling(SUM(2) OVER (PARTITION BY [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet ID] ORDER BY dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].AutoID) / (select min(SlotWidth) from CartDetails where SlotType = 'Tall'))
                end TallSlotCount FROM dbo.[CAD-CV-Cabinets]
                INNER JOIN
                dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts]
                ON dbo.[CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet ID] = dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].CabinetID
                INNER JOIN
                dbo.[CAD-CV-MateriaIs]
                ON dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].MaterialID = dbo.[CAD-CV-MateriaIs].ID WHERE                    ([CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Parts].Width > 40
                        OR [CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet Type] IN(3))
                and dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].DoorID = 0
                AND dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].DrawerID = 0
                AND dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].RollOutID = 0
                AND dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].TopID = 0 ORDER BY dbo.[CAD-CV-Cabinets].[Cabinet ID] , dbo.[CAD-CV-Parts].AutoID;
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to contain a question, btw

Comment: Please remove. Figured it out.
Answer was to do it in 3 separate queries and then query the results from that to get the totals required.

Comment: You should post your own answer as an answer, not "nah, forget it, delete this, i figured it out" - SO isn't only about helping *you*, it's about helping *everyone with the same problem as you*. Plus, if you post an answer you can get feedback on how to make it better or bugs it may contain